# NSOrderedDescending instead of NSOrderedSame for equal strings, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm compairing two strings. There are equal. `isEqualToString:` returns `NSOrderedDescending`.

I thought `isEqualToString:` would return `NSOrderedSame`. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

*example case*...

```
 NSString *myString = @"1";

 if ( [myString isEqualToString:@"1"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
    // is NSOrderedSame
 }
```

Since writing the question I know I should use instead `compare:`. It will return `NSOrderedSame`. But I would like to know, still, why this happens.

Thanks
Ross

Comment: i delete this if i could. but i am unable to...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't return `NSOrderedDescending`, it returns `YES`.  Check the return type of that method!

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

`NSOrderedDescending` is an `NSComparisonResult`, and happens to have a value of `1` due to its declaration:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

Don't mix and match types!